# android: Transition animation

Tags: android, animation, layout, transition

I have a single questionnaire layout. Is it possible that when I hit next, a transition effect occurs? Without changing anything in particular, just the animation effect to play as an illusion that the user went to the next question.

Comment: please be more specific regarding what type of animation you're looking for (alpha, translate, etc). Also, please post code & layout pertaining to the component(s) you wish to animate.

Comment: Im looking for a transition effect, just like the one when you change between layouts, I want when I click a button the transition to happen, but in the same layout, without changing anything..
I want to know if it is possible and what should i search for.

Comment: there can be many "transition effects". you could do a swipe transition, a fade transition, etc. also, it's very difficult to help if you don't show anyone what your code / layout looks like.

Comment: A swipe animation that would be. I can't upload any code.. I need the whole layout to swipe animation, what should I search for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// this animation will move the animation outside to the left.
TranslateAnimation exitAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, -exitingView.getWidth(), 0, 0);
exitAnimation.setDurtion(someDurationInMilliseconds);
exitAnimation.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
    {
        exitingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

});

exitingView.startAnimation(exitAnimation);

enteringView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
// ... create an animation for the entering view similar to above.
```

This should get you started.